xltabular and multicolumn not working well
I have a table in my document that gives me headaches. I'm sure there is a simple fix, but I cannot find it!
I want to generate a table using xltabular, with three columns and five rows. The last two columns in the last two rows should be merged and in the first merged cell, the text needs to be centred; in the last merged cell, I want it to take the whole available width. Below the code:
\begin{document}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{|l|X|X|}
\hline
\textbf{Optimisation type} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Economic (€)}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Environmental (Env)}} \\ \hline
\textbf{Goal} & Blah blah blah & blahblahblah. \\ \hline
\textbf{Method} & blablahbla & blablablah \\ \hline
\textbf{Cost function} & blahblahblah & blahblahblah \\ \hline
\textbf{Variables} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}blahblahblah 1\\ blahblahblah 2\\blahblahblah 3\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
\textbf{Battery} & \multicolumn{2}{|X|}{A longer blah blah blah that goes over several lines.} \\ \hline
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}

For now, the result I get is like so:

I would like the text in the merged cell is the last row to properly fill the whole cell, not just half.
Does anyone have an idea about how it can be solved?
Thanks a lot!

you should try your code, you have a \begin{document} before loading packages. Beside this you could try with \multicolumn{2}{|>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep\relax\linewidth=\hsize}X|} but be warned that the docu says one should do that ...

@UlrikeFischer, it worked like a charm! Thank you very much! And I swear I won't tell the docu what I did :)

hm, somehow I lost the "not", the docu says "one shouldn't do that", but I guess you got it right ;-)
